# Should I ask my manager to compensate for the unethical actions of his predecessor?

Tags: salary, ethics, salary-review

Some time ago, the company I work for decided to introduce a new way of assessing employees. According to the new rules, in any team with more than 20 members, at least one person had to receive negative evaluation, and at least one - an exceptional grade. Yep, the classic stick and carrot method. The originators noticed that there weren't many such large teams, so they decided to combine smaller ones and create such teams of over twenty people. They started to assign people to teams based on very weird criteria: for example, I ended up in a team with other JS programmers (6 people) and... Java programmers (16 people), managed by a Java team manager.

The employee's assessment was entirely up to the manager. There was almost no transparency in the evaluation rules.

For 2 years I worked so hard that I was close to the highest grade. The third year was even better than the previous years in terms of performance. I really had thought my work would be rated as exceptional.
In the meantime, a colleague had informed me that there was an interesting position open in his team. As I'd met all the criteria, I decided to apply for this position and I was accepted. My manager at the time made an agreement with my future boss that I would be able to move to the new team in 3 months.

Time had flown and the day has come to say goodbye to the old team. However, I still had to be assessed. The assessment meeting had taken place on the last day of work in the old team, and had been scheduled to end together with the end of working day. To my surprise, I got the worst grade. Attempts to prove my progress and accomplishments had failed. The assessment was irreversible.

Disappointed, I went to speak to the new manager. He told me he had known about the assessment background: my former manager was forced by the assessment process to give someone the negative evaluation. He hadn't wanted to spoil the relationships in his team, so he had given a negative opinion to the person leaving his team.
I'd calmed down a bit. Too early...

The negative assessment had its consequences: I didn't get a raise (and that year the budget was really significant), I didn't get a bonus and there were also a few minor nuisances, but the financial ones were the most devastating.

Ah, and the assessment process was terminated after 3 full years of operation due to being biased and, in many cases, unfair. And maybe because the attrition rate rose from ca. 2 per cent to over 10 per cent.

Today, two years after those events, I am still working in the "new" team. I have a new manager who is unaware of those events. Quite recently, I accidentally also found out that my teammates earn a lot more than me (wages in my company are confidential, only the salary ranges are public). That is especially frustrating when I know that in many cases I'm more involved in my work than them. And even when we get the same raises, they end up earning even more (3 per cent of 120 is more than 3 per cent of 100).

Should I ask my manager if he could give me an extra rise because of that undeserved negative evaluation? It would look like I'm asking him to make amends for someone else's fault. I know it wasn't his fault; in fact, the evaluation process itself was to blame. I'm really frustrated and have no idea how to approach this. I like my job, I like the projects I'm involved in, and I like my team even though I know that I am not treated like the others in financial terms. The only thing that bothers me is the unfairness I have become a victim of. Should I tell my manager about my concerns?

Comment: Have you considered finding a job somewhere else? This isn't something I would abide long term. Also, you'd not be asking your new manager to make amends for the actions of your previous manager, you'd be asking your new manager to correct an error that was caused due to company policy. Your previous manager was merely following his marching orders. Your previous manager was the carrier of the message, but not the author of the message.

Comment: Actually, I have considered finding another job. But in the meantime, my company replaced some people in the board of directors and it became much better place to work in. Also, thank you for sharing your point of view, I never saw it this way.

Comment: @Reevy, The point is that you're not currently being paid your true market value. So in other words, you need to ask for a bigger raise to rectify the situation and also look for another job. Another job at another employer has a much higher chance of getting the kind of raise that is going to correct this (it doesn't really matter how better the board of Directors is now. See what's out there. Test the waters at least).

Comment: Also, it should be noted that as soon as your current manager received the directive regarding the reviews, he probably knew what was going to happen to you. And it would be interesting to find out how much of a fight he put up with HR to try to exclude you from the reviewing process of the other manager since he knew that you had already given your notice, so you would be the logical choice for the worst review.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Should I ask my manager if he could give me an extra rise because of
> that undeserved negative evaluation?

No.

Ask your manager to give you an extra rise because of the value you provide to the company. Ask your manager to give you an extra rise because it will bring you into line with what you are worth on the open market.

> It would look like I'm asking him to make amends for someone else's
> fault.

It would look like that because that's exactly what you would be doing.

Comment: You can tell your manager that you'd be happy to tell them the story of why you are underpaid, but that it really doesn't matter. The past is the past. The fact today is that you are underpaid now and that needs to be fixed. The manager probably knows the company had weird policies in the past and that it has improved and needs to fix lots of things.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bit late now to do anything.

> Disappointed, I went to speak to the new manager. He told me

Here's your problem, no paper trail. With anything to do with performance or remuneration, you NEED to get a paper trail started from the beginning. Then you at least have something to work with. Do NOT trust or expect anyone else to help you. Sometimes they will, other times you'll get thrown to the dogs.

You should have pushed back as far as needed, there is no such thing as an assessment that cannot be changed or amended.

Comment: Why does it matter why he is underpaid?